# set alarm on selected time and date

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am developing a taskmanager on Android 2.1. I want to set alarm for a task set by date from datepicker and time from time picker  Help me with the code..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final EditText next = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button res = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View view) {

             int y=dp.getYear();
             int mo=dp.getMonth();
             int day=dp.getDayOfMonth();

            Time t = new Time();
                                    int h=t.getCurrentHour();
                                    int m=t.getCurrentMinutes();

    }

 private AlarmManager getSystemService(String alarmService) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey this is how to set alarm on android AlarmManager to spesific date
(android alarmmanager set alarm on date)
I have been searching all over for this.
pay attention to the value of the month!!

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
//cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

cal.set(Calendar.DATE,19);  //1-31
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER);  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);//year...

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);  //HOUR
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 39);       //MIN
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);       //SEC


// Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, alarmAct.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, 0);

//or if you start an Activity
//PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0,intent, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to set an alarm.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

//when does this go off?
Long mHowLongFromNowInMilliseconds = 10000 //(10 seconds from now)
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, mHowLongFromNowInMilliseconds);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Calendar isnt required... But it can be helpful ;)

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10000, pendingIntent);
```

!!! Remember: Alarms are canceled when the device is powered off completely.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: but i want to set it on time from time picker and date form date picker

Comment: then you need to set the calendar to that date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Android do not play alarm for you,  Alarm Manager allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.
So, simply add the time and a pending intent in the AlarmManager and when this intent will be invoked, play  music.

Visit: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlarmService extends Activity {
    private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an IntentSender that will launch our service, to be scheduled
        // with the alarm manager.
        mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this,
                0, new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService_Service.class), 0);

        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_service);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_alarm);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartAlarmListener);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_alarm);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStopAlarmListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener mStartAlarmListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
            long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            // Schedule the alarm!
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                            firstTime, 30*1000, mAlarmSender);

            // Tell the user about what we did.
            Toast.makeText(AlarmService.this, R.string.repeating_scheduled,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener mStopAlarmListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // And cancel the alarm.
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.cancel(mAlarmSender);

            // Tell the user about what we did.
            Toast.makeText(AlarmService.this, R.string.repeating_unscheduled,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
}
```